# Discontinuous Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

For

$$\displaystyle\int_0^4\! \frac{dx}{(x-1)^{1/3}}$$

there is a discontinuity at $x=1$. In the book I'm studying, it says for the continuity from the right:

$$\displaystyle\left.\lim_{x \to 1+}\frac{3}{2}(x-1)^{2/3}\right|_0^4 = \lim_{x \to 1+}\frac{3}{2}[9^{1/3}-(u-1)^{2/3}-1]$$

I don't understand where the $(u-1)^{2/3}$ term comes from. Can anyone help?

Comment: $\int \frac{1}{(x-1)^{1/3}} = \frac{3}{2}(x-1)^{2/3}$

Comment: Did you copy that correctly? The formulas with the limits make no sense, if you take a closer look.

Comment: The idea is to integrate from $0$ to $u$, where $u\lt 1$, and from $v$ to $4$, where $v\gt 1$. Add up. Take the limit as $u$ approaches $1$ from the **left**, and $v$ approaches $1$ from the right. In each case, the antiderivative is $\frac{3}{2}(x+1)^{2/3}$.

Answer (score 4):

Split up the integral around the point of discontinuity:
$$
\int_0^4 (x-1)^{-1/3}\,\mathrm dx=\lim_{y\to 1^-}\int_0^y(x-1)^{-1/3}\,\mathrm dx+\lim_{y\to 1^+}\int_y^4(x-1)^{-1/3}\,\mathrm dx\\
=\lim_{y\to 1^-}\left[\frac{3}{2}(x-1)^{2/3}\right]_0^y+\lim_{y\to 1^+}\left[\frac{3}{2}(x-1)^{2/3}\right]_y^4
$$
Calculate the expressions within the brackets, and take the limit.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.

I think there must be a mistake in the book as they've printed:


$$\displaystyle\left.\lim_{y \to 1+}\frac{3}{2}(x-1)^{2/3}\right|_0^4$$

when, as is rightly stated here, it should be:

$$\displaystyle\left.\lim_{y \to 1+}\frac{3}{2}(x-1)^{2/3}\right|_y^4$$

for the continuity from the right. I'll hopefully be able to look at this problem again tomorrow and if I need any more help, I'll hopefully be able to get some here.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Yes Ian, the first expression doesn't even involve $y$.

Answer (score 2):

You need to split the interval of integration where the problem is and then consider the limits as $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ go to zero
$$\displaystyle\int_0^4\! \frac{dx}{(x-1)^{1/3}} = \lim_{\delta \to 0^{+}}\displaystyle\int_0^{1-\delta}\! \frac{dx}{(x-1)^{1/3}}+\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\displaystyle\int_{1+\epsilon}^4\! \frac{dx}{(x-1)^{1/3}} $$

Comment: So; $1-\delta\to 1^{-}$ as $\delta\to 0$ and as Stefan noted? I want Ian to be sure of it. Thanks.

Comment: The identity in this post is wrong. See @Stefan's answer for a correct formulation.

Comment: @Did: What's wrong with this post?

Comment: You know you do not care, so why do you ask? (Please read: *The identity in this post is wrong*. This tells you that the thing which *is wrong in this post* is the identity. And the identity is the line which has an $=$ in the middle.)

Comment: @Did:Why are you assuming that I do not care? Thanks for the comment!

Comment: If you do, after the countless occurrences of the opposite behaviour, that is really good news. The fact that you modified the present post is encouraging.